# BackgroundWorker and update controls in UI

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am writing a simple POC Windows app wherein on a button click event - I use background worker DoWork method to update the Text of the UI. My understanding is Backgroundworker does the synchronization automatically and hence I should not have any problems. But am getting an error when trying to update the UI

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Hello";
    }
```

Error: [image]

Comment: What kind of error do you get? An InvokationException?

Comment: What would be the point of using a BGW at all if it did all of it's work in the UI thread?

Comment: Servy - The DoWork method is actually called on the threadpool thread and not the UI thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synchronization is done automatically only in the `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` handlers.

The code inside the `DoWork` handler is executed in a non-UI thread

Comment: Ahh very intresting - let me update the UI in RunWorkerCompleted method then and see. Thanks for this minute detail